# How to makd use of all cpus with `scrapy crawl project`?

Tags: scrapy

There are two cpus in my pc.

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep cores
cpu cores   : 2
```

1.How to know which cpu was used by `scrapy crawl project`?
2.How to makd use of all cpus with `scrapy crawl project`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy will always use 1 core for the crawl process. Crawling as such is Network I/O intensive process and doesn't need CPU power much. It is possible to use multiple processed for scrapy but not without some effort.

Please check a similar question that was answered on SO

[Scrapy Use both the CORE in the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660835/scrapy-use-both-the-core-in-the-system/45661791#45661791)